# Website - overflow a image between 2 divs

Tags: css, image, html, web

Im working on a website right now but i have some problems with putting a image on top of 2 divs, and there is a other problem the bottom div is the footer, wich i want to keep stick to the bottom ofcourse (this part works but the image on top of the divs not)

Here is a image to show you my idea better :[image]

I'd like to know a few ideas of how i can implement this, if you need to see my code ask me.

For the people who commented already under my post,
first of all thank you for your time but sadly it didnt work (so far i keep trying your suggestions)
but to help you a bit more to understand what i try to do, i give you a bit of my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/* general */
 body { background: #fdfdfd; font:  12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;  color:#444;      margin: 0 0 300px; /* bottom = footer height */}
 html { position: relative; min-height: 100%;}
 .fix_width { width: 940px; margin: 0 auto; }
 .fix_width:after, .left_foot_cont ul li:after { content: "  " ; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }

  #header { background:#6FF; height:100px; z-index: 3; position: relative;  border-top: color: #555555 thick; border-width:5px; }
  #container { position:relative; top:0px;  margin-top:100px;     overflow: auto;}
  .cont {width:250px; padding-left:20px;  margin-left:10px; display:inline-block; float:left;  }

  #footer {  background: #A9CF38;       position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;}

    img {width:940px; }


 </style>



</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
        <div class="fix_width">
<h2>
Just the header nothing important
</h2>
        </div>
</div>

     <div id = "container">
                    <div class="fix_width">
                                    <div class="cont">
                                               <h2>
                                                            Lorem ipsum
                                                </h2>
                                                <p class="last">
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
                                                </p> <!-- End p.last -->
                                    </div><!-- End .cont -->
                     </div> <!-- End .fix_width -->
          </div><!-- End .container -->

          <!-- Where should i put the image  ????? --->
          <img src="http://www.mormonshare.com/sites/default/files/handouts/cg_banner-blank.gif"> </img>


               <div id = "footer">
                    <div class="fix_width">


                                        <div class="footer_con_left">
                                                              <h2>
                                                                     Lorem ipsum
                                                                     <br /><br />
                                                            </h2>
                                                             <h1>
                                                                    dolor sit amet
                                                                    <br /> 
                                                                    dolor sit amet
                                                                    <br  />
                                                                    dolor sit amet
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    dolor sit amet      
                                                        </h1>
                                        </div>  <!-- End. footer_con_left -->
                        </div><!--  Einde class fix_width -->
      </div> <!-- Einde class footer -->

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the image in the code, i want this image to be placed 50% on the white space and 50% on the green space (so in the code between the container div and between the footer div, or maybe better to say on top of these divs)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes it would be nice to see your code, it isn't clear what element your wrapper is for example. Try setting up a test case on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should place an image in DIV1, set `position:relative` to DIV1, `position:absolute` to IMAGE and set `bottom:-50%` to IMAGE or `bottom:0px;margin-bottom:-50%;`

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should check this code I've made on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xLMxj/1/)**

**The code on the above link will center your image between your divs**

**Ignore this one .**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        background:black;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

    }
    #test1{
        width:100%;
        height:35%;
        position:relative;
        background:blue;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

    }
    #test2{
        width:100%;
        height:25%;
        position:relative;
        background:white;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

    }
    #test3{
        width:100%;
        height:40%;
        position:absolute;
        background:red;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

    }
    .content{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:white;
        float:left;
        margin:10px 0px 10px 50px;
        left:200px;
        position:relative;
    }

    </style>



</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="test1"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
    <div id="test3">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>



    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Image in a div:

```
targethoweveryouwish {
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-100px;
margin-left:-300px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Ok, heres whats going on in the code above. the 50% attributes are moving the div to the center of the page, but it is moving the top left corner of the div to the center, so you'll need to subtract half the height and width of the div to make it center properly, make those adjustments to the margin-top and margin-left properties. The z-index is basically like a 2D way to add layers to your page. Everything is on layer 0 by default, so if you want to overlap things, just put them on a higher or lower z-index. You can use negative values too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your code comes the closest now. I gonna try to play with it a bit more. Thanks so far!